# Alternate between user and computer turn (react.js card game)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given 4 players in a hearts card game where players play anticlockwise :p1 -> p2 -> p3 -> p4.

If p3 has to play first, select card for p3 and p4, then wait for user to select card, then resume to p2 to select card. 
If p4 starts, select for p4, wait for p1 and resume for p2 and p3...

This is the alternation I am trying to figure out.

Example: computer chooses

```
{p2: ['A', '♣'], p3:['2', '♣'], p4:['J', '♣'] }
```

and player chooses

```
p1:['Q', '♣']
```

In this turn, p3 starts ,then p4, then wait for p1 (user) and finally resume for p2

I tried having two states:

```
const [playerCard, setplayerCard] = useState(null)
const [compCards, setCompCard] = useState(null)
```

but am having difficulty in switching between the two. I also tried generators but am new to that topic. Any code or pseudocode that can be of guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Wondering if this will help: Create an object `rounds` like so: `const [rounds, setRounds] = useState({});`. Then, simply add each round into it. So, in the first round of play, let's say p3 is starting. Simply add: `setRounds(prev => ({ ...prev, 0: {roundStart: 'p3', p3: ['2', '♣']} }));`. Then add next player's entry (do not update `roundStart`). If next player is `p1` (assuming that's the humam), await for choice. Now, you have each round in the object. For each round, you'll know which player started the round & the cards each of them played.

Comment: does await for choice mean I have to create an asynchronous function to handle user choice? Also with setRounds, do I add it inside a useEffect or ? I am trying to work out this solution but am getting stuck as to where I setRounds and also where I call the function for user

Comment: Have a skeletal in-progress version of the hearts-game [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-currying-px9p6y).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define a bunch of functions (just like any game), whether or not the goal is reached, the current state and function to update the current state, the current turn, and a list of a actions that can be completed based on the current state of the game.

```
const enum PLAYER_TYPES {
  COMPUTER, HUMAN,
}

const gameConfig = [
  PLAYER_TYPES.HUMAN,
  PLAYER_TYPES.COMPUTER,
  PLAYER_TYPES.COMPUTER,
  PLAYER_TYPES.COMPUTER,
];

const nextTurn = (turn) => {
  return (turn % gameConfig.length) + 1;
};

const Game = () => {
  const [turn, setTurn] = useState(1);

  // Define actions that can happen based on the state of the game
  const actions = (turn) => {
    if (gameIsOver()) {
      return;
    }

    const type = gameConfig[turn - 1];

    let choice;

    switch(type) {
      case PLAYER_TYPES.HUMAN: {
        choice = await userChoice(turn);
        break;
      }

      case PLAYER_TYPES.COMPUTER: {
        choice = aiChoice(turn);
        break;
      }
    }

    setCards(turn, choice);
    setTurn(nextTurn(turn));
  };

  // Run the action for this turn
  useEffect(() => {
    actions(turn);
  }, [turn]);
};
```